# Python defining functions in Tic Tac Toe

Tags: python, tic-tac-toe

I'm in the early stages of writing a simple Tic Tac Toe game in python. I have defined 3 functions one that initializes the game, one that draws the board and one that asks if player one wants to be X or O. I feel to the best of my knowledge my functions are being requested sequentially and in proper order yet I cannot get the program to move past the first input section. Any help would be amazing.

```
def start():
    print("Do you want to play Tic Tac Toe? Type yes or no.")
    choice = input()
    while choice == ('yes','no'):
        if choice.lower == ('yes'):
           player_choice()
        elif choice.lower == ('no'):
           print("goodbye")
           quit()
        else:
              print("That was not a valid response. Type yes or no.")
start()

def drawsmall():
    a = (' ___' *  3 )
    b = '   '.join('||||')
    print('\n'.join((a, b, a, b, a, b, a, )))



def player_choice():
    print("Player one it's time to choose, X or O")
    select= input()
    if select.lower ==("x","o"):
        print("Let the game begin.")
        drawsmall()
    elif select.lower != ('x','o'):
        print("Please choose either X or O.")
    else:
        print("Come back when you're done messing around.")
        quit()
```

Comment: Can you explain, in words, the order of events which you are _expecting_ to see?

Comment: Yes I apologize. Basically, in my mind the flow looks like this. def start(), initializes the game and asks player for an input that corresponds to either yes or no. That should get passed, if yes, to player_choice, which asks player one whether they want to be X or O. player choice should pass, whether player one choose X or O to drawsmall, which should draw the actual board.

Comment: I think the first problem (without having all code is hard to know the complete flow) is here: 'if select.lower ==("x","o")', it should be 'if select.lower in ("x", "o")'; and the same for you elif, which should be just 'else:' (select might be or not equal to "x" or "o". It can not be any other thing).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see it before. Again the same here:while choice == ('yes','no'). It should be 'while choice not in ('yes', 'no'):'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after figuring out what you intended, I have seen a number of things that must be changed.

First, try this and take a look:

```
def start():
  print("Do you want to play Tic Tac Toe? Type yes or no.")
  while True:
    choice = input()
    if choice.lower() == 'yes':
      player_choice()
    elif choice.lower() == 'no':
      print("goodbye")
      quit()
    else:
      print("That was not a valid response. Type yes or no.")


def drawsmall():
  a = (' ___' * 3)
  b = '   '.join('||||')
  print('\n'.join((a, b, a, b, a, b, a,)))


def player_choice():
  print("Player one it's time to choose, X or O")
  select = input()
  if select.lower() in ("x", "o"):
    print("Let the game begin.")
    drawsmall()
  else:
    print("Please choose either X or O.")

start()
```

1. .lower, should be .lower()
2. start() must go at the end, not in the middle of the program (otherwise it will not find other functions like player_choice()
3. a string is not ('string'), you have to remove the parenthesis
4. if you want to compare a variable with several values, you have to use in, not ==
5. It's going to be hard to draw the 'X' and 'O' selected by the players when using the stdout!!!

Comment: Thank you so much. I am super new to all of this and have been trying to self teach myself. I'm very sorry I was not clear in my description earlier.

Comment: Do not worry at all! We are all learning. Try to explain your problem, what you have tried, your input and your output so people can help you the better... Do not hesitate if you make mistakes, and keep on trying! Very happy to be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

First, your problem is that you call the `lower` method wrong. you should call it like the following:

```
str = 'Test'
print(str.lower())
print(str.lower)
>> test
>> <built-in method lower of str object at 0x7ff42c83ebb0>
```

fix this issue and you will enter to the right conditions

Second you should change your `while` loop in the `start()` like the following:

```
def start():
    print("Do you want to play Tic Tac Toe? Type yes or no.")
    choice = ‘’
    while choice not in ['yes','no']:
        choice = input()
        if choice.lower() == 'yes':
           player_choice()
        elif choice.lower() == 'no':
           print("goodbye")
           quit()
        else:
              print("That was not a valid response. Type yes or no.")
```

notice the if you won't set `choice = ''` you will not enter The loop.

Third, you should move the calling to the `start()` function to the end of all the function deceleration in order for them all to be properly recognized.

**Note**

correct the `player_choice()` with the logic I provided you in my `start()`